# How to Install Oracle 11gR2 on Ubuntu Server 13.04

Tags: ubuntu, oracle-database

I want to install Oracle 11gR2 for Linux on Ubuntu Server 13.04.

I have downloaded Oracle 11gR2 for Linux, and when I execute use runinstaller it require GUI supported files.

While Google I got things related rpm packages. Help me to install it.

Comment: rpm packages don't work with Ubuntu.  Any reason stopping you from installing GUI support?

Comment: @Mitch, If my understanding is right, ubuntu server not come with gui, Also I saw that related rpm package on some blogs.

Comment: I know, but you can install a GUI if you want to.

Answer (score 2):

To install GUI on Ubuntu Server, just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

When done do:

```
sudo apt-get install --no-install-recommends ubuntu-desktop
```

This command will install the Ubuntu Desktop, without all the desktop add-on and other things that come with Ubuntu Desktop Edition.

When done, just reboot, and you're done.

Other option that you can have:

For XFCE

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install xubuntu-desktop
```

For KDE

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install kubuntu-desktop
```

For LXDE

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install lxde
```

After you install the GUI of choice, proceed with the installation of Oracle 11gR2.  You can check [here](http://installoracle11gonubuntu.blogspot.com/2013/06/how-to-install-and-getting-started-on.html) for complete instructions, its for 12.10, but should work for 13.04

Answer (score 1):

You can also install Oracle via the command line (also known as 'kickstart', automatic or silent install). See https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/42926/how-to-automate-oracle-db-installation-like-a-hands-free-install for details.

Note that only for the Express version RPMs are available. The Standard-Edition is only available via two zip-files. The express version contains less features and has more limitations, e.g. it does not contain the Pro*C embedded SQL preprocessor.